# Share xampp on lan

Tags: apache, xampp, lan

I just installed `XAMPP 7.2.5` on my `Windows 10 x64` computer.

When I type [localhost](http://localhost) in my browser, i go into `XAMPP dashboard` page and anything is OK.

I want to access dashboard page (`htdocs` folder actually) from other devices in same network (LAN), but cannot do this!

I have static IP address on this PC (`192.168.1.100`), when i type this IP address in browser of my Android phone (or another windows pc on local network), and get this error: "**192.168.1.100** is unreachable"

I tried this solutions but not helped:

- Turn off windows defender firewall (**I have not any Antivirus but
  Default windows defender**)
- Add exception for tcp 80 port to inbound firewall rules

I search the internet and stackoverflow for 5 hours but noting found!
I tried lot of solutions about httpd.conf but nothing help me.

---

### EDIT

I run XAMPP Control Panel with administrator permission, Now i can access htdocs from other windows computer, but still cannot access it from Android device!

Answer (score 0):

It's the solution worked for me:

- Disable your UAC from control panel (Low Level - Don't warn).
- Run XAMPP control panel as Administrator.